# Serial port communication between nRf52840 dongle and Raspberry pi 4 using Ble

Tags: bluetooth

I need to pass a stream of data from raspberry pi 4 to PC through Ble. I can successfully build and run \examples\peripheral\usbd_ble_uart. It can communicate with my android phone using nRF connect app.

I like to connect the nRf52840 to raspberry pi and work through serial communication.

```
sudo bluetoothctl

agent on

default-agent

scan on

pair 98:D3:31:xx:xx:xx

trust 98:D3:31:xx:xx:xx

quit

sudo rfcomm connect hci0 98:D3:31:xx:xx:xx
```

It shows the error Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Host is down

But I can do the same step for HC-05 Bluetooth module and work well.

Is there any way to tackle this problem?

any comments appreciate

Comment: But HC-05 is BT, not BLE. Perhaps you can try AT09 BLE or similar, to make sure Rpi4B/AT09 BLE works, before trying your luck on nRF52840. BTW, buster 2020feb13 release might have solved the teething problems on bluez552. So you may like to upgrade buster first.